# SSH /osync Escape "@" character in remote file path

Tags: ssh, rsync, synology

I needed to write a script which syncs multiple directories from local to remote server (bi-directionally).

This script currently uses [osync.sh](https://github.com/deajan/osync) which uses `ssh` to perform the synchronization. The exact command it uses (which causes my script to fail is located in line 1485 in the `osync.sh` file on Github):

```
$SSH_CMD env LC_ALL=C env _REMOTE_TOKEN="$_REMOTE_TOKEN" bash -s << 'ENDSSH' >> "$RUN_DIR/$PROGRAM.${FUNCNAME[0]}.$SCRIPT_PID.$TSTAMP" 2>&1
```

This is basically just one `ssh` command.

We were using `rsync` for replication, and it did work as intended even with this file path structure. But osync does not.

---

The **problem**: The command I need to run is:

```bsh
osync.sh --initiator="/var/services/homes/@DH-ADS/0/localUser-1/local-folder-to-sync/" --target="ssh://sync-user@DOMAIN:25//var/services/homes/@DH-ADS/0/remoteUser-1/remote-folder-to-sync" --rsakey="/var/services/homes/sync-user/.ssh/id_rsa" --summary --dry --verbose
```

Where:

- localUser and remoteUser have the same name (Active Directory /LDAP Username)
- the sync-user also has the same name on both servers
- The ssh-key is correct and working.

This command works just fine, if there is no "@" character in the file path. So I think the problem is this character. I cannot change the file path, because it is a Synology Server and this is the default path for Active Directory Users.

The error:

```bsh
TIME: 0 - This is an unstable dev build [2021062901]. Please use with caution.
TIME: 0 - -------------------------------------------------------------
TIME: 0 - Fri Dec  3 11:34:46 CET 2021 - osync 1.3.0-dev-rc2 script begin.
TIME: 0 - -------------------------------------------------------------
TIME: 0 - Sync task [quicksync_task] launched as sync-user@local-server (PID 22970)
sync-user@REMOTE_DOMAIN (without tld and last character [example.de -> exampl)@REMOTE-SERVER-DOMAIN (correct)'s password:
```

As you can see it asks for a password for a user, which I did not specify in any way. And I think the reason is the "@" character in the remote file path (and in the local one maybe too).

I have tried to use '' but then the remote file path and local file path are not found (because it assumes the ' is part of the file path):

```bsh
osync.sh --initiator="'/var/services/homes/@DH-ADS/0/localUser-1/local-folder-to-sync/'" --target="'ssh://sync-user@DOMAIN:25//var/services/homes/@DH-ADS/0/remoteUser-1/remote-folder-to-sync'" --rsakey="/var/services/homes/sync-user/.ssh/id_rsa" --summary --dry --verbose
TIME: 0 - This is an unstable dev build [2021062901]. Please use with caution.
TIME: 0 - Local replica path [/var/services/homes/@DH-ADS/0/localUser-1/local-folder-to-sync/] does not exist or is not writable and CREATE_DIRS is not allowed.
TIME: 0 - Local replica path ['ssh://video-sync@REMOTE_DOMAIN:25//var/services/homes/@DH-ADS/0/remoteUser-1/remote-folder-to-sync/'/] does not exist or is not writable and CREATE_DIRS is not allowed.
TIME: 0 - _ExecTasksPidsCheck called by [CheckReplicas] finished monitoring pid [22142] with exitcode [1].
TIME: 0 - _ExecTasksPidsCheck called by [CheckReplicas] finished monitoring pid [22143] with exitcode [1].
TIME: 0 - Cancelling task.
TIME: 0 - osync finished with errors.
```

So is there any way to escape the "@" character in the file path for ssh command?  Is the error something else?

I have tested the Write permissions and Create-dirs permissions. Everything is allowed and does work.

I have also tested with the version osync.sh 1.2 (which is latest stable release a few years old) and it also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the source code of the script you linked and digging into the `function Init { ... }`, **yes, the issue is with `@` character in your path** as that script truncates the shortest suffix from the given path (`${parameter%@*}` in bellow), so it causes to take wrong remote-userName in:

```
if [[ "$uri" == *"@"* ]]; then
            # remove everything after '@'
            REMOTE_USER=${uri%@*}
```

it will end-up to set REMOTE_USER to *`sync-user@DOMAIN:25//var/services/homes/`* which is wrong; script owner could fix this by using longest match stripping `${parameter%%@*}` instead;

or modify the `osync.sh` script that part which I mentioned by yourself, and install again;

---

Notes:

1. use only single quotes around that path not both of them like `--target='/some/remote/path'`.
2. As I read the script some other parts, it will have issues with `=` and `:` characters too if you have them in your paths.
3. I'm not sure if pointed issue would be the only issue here.